# Colouring by variable when using tidy graph in R?

Tags: r, ggraph, tidygraph

I am trying to come up with a way to consistently colour multiple `tidygraph` plots. Right now, the issue is, when I plot multiple plots to the screen at once, `tidygraph` chooses a different colour for each variable. hopefully my example below will explain the issue.

To begin, I create some data, turn them into `tidygraph` objects, and put them together into a list:

```
library(tidygraph)
library(ggraph)
library(gridExtra)

# create some data for the tbl_graph
nodes <- data.frame(name = c("x4", NA, NA),
                    label = c("x4", 5, 2))

nodes1 <- data.frame(name = c("x4", "x2", NA, NA, "x1", NA, NA),
                    label = c("x4", "x2", 2,   1, "x1", 2, 7))

edges <- data.frame(from = c(1,1), to = c(2,3))
edges1 <- data.frame(from = c(1, 2, 2, 1, 5, 5),
                    to    = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7))

# create the tbl_graphs
tg <- tbl_graph(nodes = nodes, edges = edges)
tg_1 <- tbl_graph(nodes = nodes1, edges = edges1)


# put into list
myList <- list(tg, tg_1)
```

Then I have a plotting function that allows me to display all the plots at once. I do this using `grid.arrange` from the `gridExtra` package, like so:

```
plotFun <- function(List){
ggraph(List, "partition") +
  geom_node_tile(aes(fill = name), size = 0.25) +
  geom_node_label(aes(label = label, color = name)) +
  scale_y_reverse() +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
}

# Display all plots
allPlots <- lapply(myList, plotFun)
n <- length(allPlots)
nRow <- floor(sqrt(n))
do.call("grid.arrange", c(allPlots, nrow = nRow))
```

This will produce something like this:
[image: example plot]

As you can see, it colours by the variable `label` for each individual plot. This results in the same variable `label` being coloured differently in each plot. For example, `x4` in the first plot is red and in the second plot is blue.

I'm trying to find a way to make the colours for the variable's `label` consistent across all plots. Maybe using `grid.arrange` isn't the best solution!?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since each plot doesn't know anything about the other plots, it's best to assign colors yourself. First you can extract all the node names and assign them a color

```
nodenames <- unique(na.omit(unlist(lapply(myList, .%>%activate(nodes) %>% pull(name) ))))
nodecolors <- setNames(scales::hue_pal(c(0,360)+15, 100, 64, 0, 1)(length(nodenames)), nodenames)
nodecolors 
#        x4        x2        x1 
# "#F5736A" "#00B734" "#5E99FF"
```

We use `scales::hue_pal` to get the "default" ggplot colors but you could use whatever you like. Then we just need to customize the color/fill scales for the plots with these colors.

```
plotFun <- function(List, colors=NULL){
  plot <- ggraph(List, "partition") +
    geom_node_tile(aes(fill = name), size = 0.25) +
    geom_node_label(aes(label = label, color = name)) +
    scale_y_reverse() +
    theme_void() +
    theme(legend.position = "none")
    if (!is.null(colors)) {
      plot <- plot + scale_fill_manual(values=colors) + 
        scale_color_manual(values=colors, na.value="grey")
    }
  plot
}
allPlots <- lapply(myList, plotFun, colors=nodecolors)
n <- length(allPlots)
nRow <- floor(sqrt(n))
do.call("grid.arrange", c(allPlots, nrow = nRow))
```

[image: plot with coordinating node name colors]